# usage of this in oop of javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

code like this:

```
var Policy={
    initialize:function(){
        return function(){
               this.initialize.apply(this,arguments);
        };
    }
};
var AjaxLoadingPolicy= Policy.initialize();//(1)
AjaxLoadingPolicy.prototype={
    initialize:function(name){
        this.name=name;
    }
};
```

Base on this code AjaxLoadingPolicy is a function with this.initialize.apply(this,arguments) in (1). But I don't really understand what this.initialize is. and why it can be defined in AjaxLoadingPolicy.prototype? Also, isn't that apply is used to apply the supperclass priorities to the instance?

Comment: I have no idea why this is downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At (1) in the code, the value of *AjaxLoadingPolecy* is assigned a reference to a new function object with the body:

```
function(){
    this.initialize.apply(this,arguments);
};
```

The value of `this` when that function is called can only be determined by seeing how it is called. If it is called simply as `AjaxLoadingPolecy()` then `this` will reference the global object (or undefined in strict mode).

The object assigned to `AjaxLoadingPolecy.prototype` has an *initialize* method that is inherited by instances of *AjaxLoadingPolecy* (i.e. objects created by `new AjaxLoadingPolecy()`), it is not inherited by *AjaxLoadingPolecy* itself.

Objects inherit from their constructor's public prototype (called the instance's internal `[[Prototype]]`), not their own public prototype.

Incidentally, in the OP, the following:

```
AjaxLoadingPolicy.prototype={
    initialize:function(name){
        this.name=name;
    }
};
```

is exactly the same as:

```
AjaxLoadingPolicy.prototype.initialize = function(name) {
    this.name=name;
};
```

The second uses the existing prototoype object, whereas the former replaces it (using more code and wasting the instantiation of an object).

`apply` is used to set a function's `this` and supply arguments. Javascript doesn't have classes (or super classes), though `apply` and `call` might be used when emulating that behaviour.